# How do you exclude applications from the 'open with' menu

Tags: macos, shortcut-menu

I've got quite a list of installed application. The result is there are many applications bloating the 'open with' menu.

Is there a way to exclude applications from the 'open with' menu?

If it's possible to exclude applications from both certain file types and from all file types, that would be great.

Comment: Thank you for asking this question.  I've got it even worse than you do—I'm a developer, so I have archived versions of every major version of my app on my Mac (part of Xcode's archive functionality), and all of those archives show up in the list!  Worse, all versions accept the same files, so macOS doesn't seem to want to let me manually set it for the newest version; instead it tenaciously hangs on to an older, buggy version as the default!

Answer (score -1):

No, they're included automatically by the OS, but if you want to reset the file, you can try this:

1. Open Terminal in /Applications
2. Type the following command: 
   `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user`
3. Relaunch Finder, click `cmd`+`alt`+`esc` and select Finder and click Relaunch
4. Now the "Open With..." menu is reseted!

Comment: To whomever gave this answer a negative tick - it would have been useful to know why this answer is unsatisfactory.

Comment: @Bill More interested would be if there is something you've found to contradict the minus. Should I use this or not. That is the question.

Comment: It actually works, so far...

Comment: Fcuk mac and apple. Spent months on this, reset spotlight, exclude and everything.